# The program can't start because msvcr90.dll is missing

Tags: python, pywin32, msvcrt

I have using 'PythonWin' build 218 for 64 bit Windows 7 and using 'Python 2.7.8'

When i run my application i get this MSVCR90.dll missing error.

When I run dependency tool on my exe I see that Python 27.dll can find MSVCR90.dll that it needs from win sxs folder. However Pywintypes27.dll is not able to load the same dll.

Tried running 'sxstrace'. It produces a  binary trace file, however when i parse that file it produces an empty output file !

I have installed VC++ Redistribute and SP1. HOw do I find out which version of side by side dll PYWINTYPES.dll is dependent on. I tried copying all 64 bit versions of msvcr90.dll I have in my machine one by one to exe path, with no luck. Is there a way to force to use one of the msvcr90.dlls ?

Comment: Are you sure you installed the 64-bit version of Python? I've made this mistake before with the same results.

Comment: Yes I have When I run dependency Walker I can see Python27.dll has "64" symbol. so does PythonCom.dll and PyWinTypes.dll. Problem is Python27 and Pywintypes27.dll have dependency on diffferent version of MSVCR90.dll. How do I force them to be the same ?

Comment: You can't exactly force them. If you open the DLLs in question, either in Visual Studio or a text editor, you might be able to take a look at the manifest to see if it mentions a specific sxs version it requires.

Comment: I opened the dlls in Resource Hacker and observed that Python27.dll  had a specific sxs version, and PyWinTypes.dll did not. I edited that to have same sxs version as Python27.dll. I dont see the dll missing error now, but now I get application was not able to start correctly error.